# Only allow cross-fork PR from specific Bitbucket branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request, git-fork

So there's this org which has a certain highly regulated Bitbucket repo R in a centrally-governed project C. We maintain a synchronized fork of C/R, T/R, in our own Bitbucket project T. To make a change, we have to

- create a branch T/R:feature-branch
- push a change to it
- submit a PR from T/R:feature-branch to C/R:master and get an approval from the governance team for C.

This situation has led on more than one occasion to certain changes submitted by different subteams interfering with other subteams of T. To try and prevent this problem, I want to impose the restriction that all cross-fork PRs and merges into C/R come from a specifically designated master-like branch in T/R, so that the dev branches are serialized onto that branch and undergo local reviews before we "throw them over the wall".

Given that we have no control over the permissions or settings of C or C/R, what options do I have to enforce that cross-fork PRs may only come from T/R:local-master branch?

Comment: what is the point of working on the fork and not directly with C/R? What are you trying to benefit while doing so ?

Comment: of course we would prefer to create branches in C or create the rules in C/R, but that is not allowed. hence my question.

Comment: Bitbucket has an extension called ScriptRunner you can have custom events listener and react on them. One of such events is - PullRequestOpenRequestedEvent, it might be the one or something similar event that would be triggered and processed to prevent even creation of PRs if target branch is not the one you expect. I did not work with forks as such, but i am sure with ScriptRunner you can tune what is allowed and what is not. I personally use ScriptRunner for many different guards to harden the workflow.